# using the jquery idleTimeout and enabling multiplewindowsupport

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the jquery idletimeout on my system and i have one question even i have enabled multiplewindow support, how can i blink a tab or highlight that when a modal opens up in that tab

so if i am on google.com or somewhere else, i should notice that something is up

my code is like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    IdleTimeoutPlus.start({
                        idleTimeLimit: 240,
                        warnTimeLimit : 120,
                        
                        multiWindowSupport: true,
                        idleCheckHeartbeat : 60,
                        activityEvents : 'keypress',
                        warnCountdownBar : true
                        
                    });
                });
```

Comment: A couple of questions: 1.) have you made sure that all of the dependencies to run this are present: jQuery +2.2, jQuery UI +1.11 or Bootstrap +3.3, jQuery Storage API, jQuery BlockUI 2.) If so, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: yes, i have all the relevant files and for storage i used foragestoorage plugin

Comment: I've already asked this, but you didn't respond... but, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: nopes no, errors i actually managed to made it work, i have anotehr issue but it seems its quite unrrelated but its interesting one, i get an error when two modal windows try to open at same  time `cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'`